# InDesign Script - remove element from odd pages

Tags: javascript, printing, scripting, adobe-indesign

I have a single page layout that is duplicated and each page has a 'region' section on the right had side.

Is it possible to remove this 'region' section  from all odd pages using a script? Otherwse I'll have to delete them manually.

Comment: Uh yes it certainly seems possible. However, it is not the purpose of Stack Overflow to post a task here and ask for a ready-made script.

Comment: I didn't ask for a ready-made script, just some pointers on where to start. I thought this was a question and answer site.